# jComboBox item from database and fill jTextfield when the item from jComboBox selected

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

i tried to load the JcomboBox with some query by JOIN to other table and the item in the JcomboBox is id from table1, name from table2, loan date from table1. When I select the item from JcomboBox  I want to fill the JTextField with loan amount from table1.

This is my loadCombo

```
public void loadComboGadai() {
    try {
        comboDataGadai.removeAllItems();
        comboDataGadai.addItem("-- Pilih --");
        sql = "SELECT * FROM gadai INNER JOIN nasabah ON gadai.ktp_gadai = nasabah.ktp";
        res = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        while(res.next()) {
            String no_Gadai = res.getString("no_gadai");
            String nama_Nasabah = res.getString("nama_nasabah");
            String jatuh_tempo = res.getString("jatuh_tempo");
            comboDataGadai.addItem(no_Gadai+" : "+nama_Nasabah+" : "+jatuh_tempo);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

And this is get data from the combo

```
public void getGadai() {

    try {
        if (comboDataGadai.getSelectedIndex() > 0) {
        comboDataGadai.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        sql = "SELECT * FROM gadai INNER JOIN nasabah ON gadai.ktp_gadai = nasabah.ktp";
        res = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        if (res.next()) {
            String jumlah_Tebusan = res.getString("jumlah_tebusan");
            txtJumlahTebusan.setText(jumlah_Tebusan);
        }

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The only comment I can make is don't use an empty catch block. You should display the Exception in case you have SQL errors.

Comment: Instead of using `String` to hold all you data, create a POJO, which can hold the individual properties.  Then use a `ListCellRenderer` to modify the way in which these POJOs are rendered by the `JComboBox`.  When selected, you can get the instance of the POJO which was selected and update the text field accordingly